# Chain/Nested java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, chaining

I have a number of evaluations I'm looking to make to a collection of data and I've been trying to figure out how to accomplish this with streams. I'm looking at streams specifically because the collection sizes can be fairly large and i'd like to take advantage of the parallel processing.

Here is some sample code, which reflects a basic structure -

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;

public class TestApplication {

  /***
   * Enumerated list of various product types
   ***/
  public enum ProductType {
    TOY, BATH,  BEDROOM, OUTDOOR
  }

  /***
   * Represents each product we have in inventory.
   ***/
  class Product {
    public String name;
    public ProductType type;
    public int quantity = 0;
    public double costPerUnit = 0;
    public double productValue = 0;
    public float percentOfTotalInventory;

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setProductType(ProductType type) { this.type = type; }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) { this.quantity = quantity; }
    public void setCostPerUnit(double unitCost) { this.costPerUnit = unitCost; }

    public void calculateProductValue() {
      this.productValue = quantity * costPerUnit;
    }

    public void calculatePercentageOfTotalInventory(double totalInventoryValue) {
      this.percentOfTotalInventory = (float) ((costPerUnit * 100) / totalInventoryValue);
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public ProductType getType() { return type; }
    public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
    public double getCostPerUnit() { return costPerUnit; }
    public float getPercentOfTotalInventory() { return percentOfTotalInventory; }
  }

  /***
   * summary of all the products in our inventory.
   *
   * in addition to the catalog of products, will keep a running total cost of
   * the current inventory and a summary grouping of the products by type
   ***/
  class ProductInventory {
        public List<Product> products;
        public BigDecimal totalCostOfInventory;
        public Map<ProductType, List<ProductSummaryByType>> productsByType;

      public void accept(Product p) {
         p.calculateProductValue();
         products.add(p);
         totalCostOfInventory = totalCostOfInventory.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(p.getCostPerUnit()));
       }

      public void combine(ProductInventory other) {
         this.products.addAll(other.products);
         this.totalCostOfInventory = totalCostOfInventory.add(other.totalCostOfInventory);
      }
  }

  private class ProductSummaryByType {
    //for a type (toy, bath, bed)
    public ProductType Type;

    //provide total value of inventory for this product type
    public double value;
    public float percentageOfTotal;

    public void calcPercentOfTotal(double total) {
        //given the typeValuation, calculate percentage of the total inventory is this type?
        this.percentageOfTotal = (float) ((this.value * 100) / total);
    }
  }

 private Map<String, BigDecimal> getProductPrice(String productName) {
   //get current price for product
   Map<String, BigDecimal> productInfo = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();
   //simulate the pricing
   productInfo.put(productName, BigDecimal.ONE);
   return productInfo;
 }

  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    //provide product list and process stream
  }
}
```

For a collection of Products, each Product will have a varying purchase price each day, so there is a different routine to set the costPerUnit.

I'm looking to:

- iterate over the list of products and capture a collection of the product names

  - e.g: `List<String> productNames = productList.stream().map(Product::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());`
- Map the names to a function to get the current price

  - e.g: `productNames.stream().map(this::getProductPrice).collect(Collectors.toList());`
- For each item in the updated price list, set the `costPerUnit` for each matching instance in the product inventory collection
- For each instance of the product, calculate the cost (`calculateProductValue`) on each instance and add to the `ProductInventory`, I assume as a custom collector, so it can calculate the total cost of all inventory
- with total cost of all inventory, calculate the `percentOfTotalInventory` for each product by calling the `calculatePercentageOfTotalInventory`
- lastly, group the inventory by `ProductType` with the total value for the group (adding the `productValue` for each instance in the group) and calculate the `percentageOfTotal` for the group in the ProductSummaryByType class
- the `ProductInventory` class should be fully populated at the end of the chain

Again, the reason for trying to do this with nested logic is because I'd like to invoke with parallelism. If you have any suggestions on how best to accomplish, I could use the guidance.

Comment: How large is "fairly large?"  More than 100,000 elements?  More than one million?  Would a database actually be a better idea?

Comment: At this time not larger than 30k. I’ve evaluated the db route and simply wanted to understand how to chain the logic together in code.

Comment: You should try something instead of writing down the requirements

Comment: Write it using loops, then the stream part should come easily, if possible